# sudo apt-get update display message connecting for infinite time

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

sudo **apt-get update** display message **connecting** for a long time and later time-out error is thrown. I have also tired cleaned up /var/lib/apt/lists/* and I have tried all the help from google but no luck.

[ScreenShort of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAxXZ.png)

Comment: Can you open any of the repositories in a browser? Does internet work at all?

Comment: @SorenA Yes I can and yes I do have internet I am posting the comment from the same system